# "Out of stack space " while using jquery dialog in a jqgrid

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jqgrid

I'm having a jqgrid and on the **loadComplete** of the grid i am calling a function that creates a new div with some custom classes and appends that div to one of the columns where i am displaying the custom image button created in the div. 
Now, on the click of the image button i am displaying a modal dialog form. On my modal dialog form i am getting some value by making a ajax call for the selected record .Also there are two buttons ( save and cancel) on the dialog. When **.dialog("close")** method is called after save or on close, i am getting a error "**SCRIPT28: Out of stack space** " and Strangely the save also works fine.

Can anybody assist on that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've apparently got some recursive code? It looks like you're descending too far in the recursion. Javascript has to be protective of its memory space, because it's usually going to potentially have a lot of ops per tab.

Comment: @jcolebrand : yes you are correct. i figured this later..... there was some recursive code  in it. i was able to replicate that. 

Anyhow Thanks a lot!!!